# Trigger WebJob from another WebJob using Azure SDK for Java

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is it possible to trigger a WebJob from another WebJob, using the [Azure SDK for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java) (without having to make HTTP calls to the WebJobs REST API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, there is not even webjob sdk for java, so the function you want could only be implemented with the [Kudu webjob API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job).

However if you want to try with the .NET webjob sdk, you could implement it with queue trigger. Make your first webjob a queue trigger one, then in another webjob add a queue to trigger the first one. And it's still no for now, there is not sdk method to trigger webjob.